# Related to Scheduling

Tags: linux

I would like to know the ratio of high processes to low priority processes running at ant given time in real time?
What factors does it depend on?

Answer (score 0):

You have hundreds of processes running on Linux/Unix to compare just one,two or a group, regardless their priority, does not make sense. There are many tools of choice:

- top
- pidstat
- perf
- ...

Interesting information you'll get also from `man 5 proc` section: `/proc/[pid]/stat`

Look also for [procstat](http://brokestream.com/procstat.html)